# SCCM Report to identify machines with 64-bit capable hardware

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, sccm, report

Currently looking at deployment options for Windows 7. One of the questions we're looking into is 32 bit vs 64 bit. I'm trying to run a SCCM report against our estate to identify which machines are 64-bit capable (whether or not they're currently running a 64-bit OS).

There seem to be a few resources out on the net for this ([here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/configmgrinventory/thread/046f0161-4fb4-4cc7-ab92-e9d0c9b84f06), [here](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/skissinger/archive/2009/06/23/32bit-vs-64bit-report.aspx) and [here](http://smsug.ca/blogs/garth_jones/archive/2009/01/28/count-of-os-and-bite-size-32-bit-or-64-bit.aspx)) but none of them seem to work right on machines running 32-bit Windows XP. 32-bit XP machines seem to always report that they're running on 32-bit hardware.

The query I'm currently running is:

```
select sys.netbios_name0, sys.Operating_System_Name_and0 as OperatingSystem, 
case when pr.addresswidth0=64 then '64bit OS'
when pr.addresswidth0=32 then '32bit OS'
end as [Operating System Type],
case when pr.DataWidth0=64 then '64bit Processor'
when pr.DataWidth0=32 then '32bit Processor'
end as [Processor Type],
case when pr.addresswidth0=32 and pr.DataWidth0=64 then 'YES'
end as [32-bit OS on x64 processor]
from v_r_system sys
join v_gs_processor pr on sys.resourceid=pr.resourceid
```

I've also tried this, which reports all "Windows XP Professional" systems are on "X86-based PC", not x64 based even though a number of them definitely are:

```
select
    OS.Caption0,
    CS.SystemType0,
    Count(*)
from
    dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM CS Left Outer Join dbo.v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM OS on CS.ResourceID = OS.ResourceId
Group by
    OS.Caption0,
    CS.SystemType0
Order by
    OS.Caption0,
    CS.SystemType0
```

For instance we have a set of Dell Latitude E4200 laptops. Some of these are running 32-bit Windows XP SP3, some of them are running 32-bit Windows 7, some are running 64-bit Windows 7. All the laptops are identical, having come from the same order. Out of these the Windows 7 (32 and 64-bit) report that the hardware is 64-bit capable, and the Windows XP machines report that they're only 32-bit capable.

Does anyone know if there's another value I can query to get the hardware's capabilities correctly on XP, or is there a hotfix that will get it reporting the correct info?

Comment: Just note that you will find very few 63-bit computers on your network :)

Comment: Lol oops, well at least it was only mis-typed in my description, not the actual queries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a feeling that posting on here would be what made me find the actual answer myself!

Have found a property of the system processor that seems to answer the question exactly right on all OS's I've tested with (server & workstation from XP/2003 up). What I have is `v_GS_PROCESSOR.Is64Bit0` which gives a `1` or a `0` depending on whether or not the CPU is 64-bit capable.

My SCCM queries now are (for a top-down summary):

```
select
    OS.Caption0,
    case when pr.Is64Bit0=1 then '64-bit'
    when pr.Is64Bit0=0 then '32-bit'
    end as [Processor Type],
    Count(*)
from
    dbo.v_gs_processor PR Left Outer Join dbo.v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM OS on PR.ResourceID = OS.ResourceId
Group by
    OS.Caption0,
    pr.Is64Bit0
Order by
    OS.Caption0,
    pr.Is64Bit0
```

And (for the machine by machine listing):

```
select sys.netbios_name0, sys.Operating_System_Name_and0 as OperatingSystem, 
case when pr.Is64Bit0=1 then 'Yes 64-bit'
when pr.Is64Bit0=0 then 'No 32-bit'
end as [Processor Is 64-Bit?],
case when pr.addresswidth0=64 then '64-bit OS'
when pr.addresswidth0=32 then '32-bit OS'
end as [Operating System Type],
case when pr.DataWidth0=64 then '64-bit Processor'
when pr.DataWidth0=32 then '32-bit Processor'
end as [Processor Type (XP Lies)],
case when pr.addresswidth0=32 and pr.Is64Bit0=1 then 'YES'
end as [32-bit OS on x64 processor]
from v_r_system sys
join v_gs_processor pr on sys.resourceid=pr.resourceid
```